# SVG hover not changing color as expected

Tags: html, css, image, svg, hover

Original question was vague.

I am editing a web template that uses three "font-awesome" glyphicons. They transition from white to orange, smoothly, as I hover over them. I found one icon that I really like that can be found on the icomoon.io/app page by searching "paint."

They provide me with a reference link to put into the body of my html. Which is:

```
<symbol id="icon-paint-format" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
<title>paint-format</title>
<path class="path1" d="M1024 576v-384h-192v-64c0-35.2-28.8-64-64-64h-704c-35.2 0-64 28.8-64 64v192c0 35.2 28.8 64 64 64h704c35.2 0 64-28.8 64-64v-64h128v256h-576v128h-32c-17.674 0-32 14.326-32 32v320c0 17.674 14.326 32 32 32h128c17.674 0 32-14.326 32-32v-320c0-17.674-14.326-32-32-32h-32v-64h576zM768 192h-704v-64h704v64z"></path>
```

And then to reference it by using:

```
<svg class="icon icon-paint-format"><use xlink:href="#icon-paint-format"></use></svg>
```

The html for the 3 icons looks like this:

```
<div class="work-grids">
                <div class="col-md-4 work-grid">
                    <span class="col-md-5 w-icon"> <i class="fa fa-phone"> </i></span>
                    <div class="col-md-7 work-info">
                        <h4>Research</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 work-grid center-work-grid">
                    <span class="col-md-5 w-icon"> <i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
                    <div class="col-md-7 work-info">
                        <h4>Design</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 work-grid">
                    <span class="col-md-5 w-icon"><img src="images/paint-format.svg"></span>
                    <div class="col-md-7 work-info">
                        <h4>Develop</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                <div class="work-map">
                    <span> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!---- //End-work-grids----->
```

As you can see by the third div class I used:

```
<img src="images/paint-format.svg">
```

To import the svg icon.

Now, the corresponding css for all three icons is this:

```
/*---- start-work----*/
.work{
    background: #4F4F57;
    padding: 5em 0;
}
.work-head h3,.work-head p{
    color:#FFF;
}
.work-grid span{
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ff9000;
    border:6px solid #ffddb0;
    border-radius:30em;
    -webkit-border-radius:30em;
    -moz-border-radius:30em;
    -o-border-radius:30em;
    -ms-border-radius:30em;
    z-index: 999;
    transition:0.5s all;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s all;
    -o-transition:0.5s all;
    -ms-transition:0.5s all;
}
.w-icon{
    text-align:center;
}
.w-icon i{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    margin-top: 1.4em;
    transition:0.5s all;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s all;
    -o-transition:0.5s all;
    -ms-transition:0.5s all;
}
.work-info h4{
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.6em
}
.work-info p{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
.work-grids{
    margin-top:4em;
}
.center-work-grid{
    margin-top: 8em;
}
.work-grids{
    position: relative;
}
.work-map{
    width: 850px;
    height: 237px;
    background: url(../images/work-map.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:10%;
}
.work-grid:hover span{
    background:#F3F3F3;
    border-color:#EBEBEB;
}
.work-grid:hover .w-icon i{
    color:#ff9000;
}
/*---- //End-work----*/
```

All I edited from the template was change non-hovered icon colour .w-icon to #fff (white) and then have them smoothly transition to #ff9000 (orange) as my mouse hovers over them. The first two glyphicons are a success, meanwhile the third one will not:

A) appear to be white when not hovered over and;
B) transition (smoothly) to orange when hovered over

I hope I have cleared up the question

Comment: I don't see your `.paint-icon` selector in your second set of HTML markup. I don't believe you can style an SVG element when you include the SVG as the source of an image tag. Is there a reason you're not using the custom icomoon icon font?

Comment: you're right, but when I change the selector back to .work-grids or .w-icons it also doesn't change anything.

Comment: Right about what? You question is a bit vague and so are your responses. It's going to be difficult to help because the code and questions don't seem to be aligned.

Comment: Images are not interactive. You'd need to load them via some other tag e.g. `<object>` or `<iframe>` or load them inline.

Comment: @hungerstar Sorry.

When I change the <span class="col-md-5 w-icon"> to <span class="col-md-5 paint-icon"> or <span class="col-md-5 w-icon"> to <span class="col-md-5 paint-icon">

and then apply the css that I provided it (the svg icon) does not 1) appear white, and 2) transition to orange.

Would it be possible to perhaps show you my files so that you can understand what I'm trying to convey?

Comment: Again, is there a reason you're using SVG instead of the icon font?

Comment: @hungerstar

To be honest I have no clue. I'm learning html/css as I go and I just wanted to use this the paint-format icon that icomoon provided because it fits well with the purpose of the website.

I don't even know what an Icon font is at the moment.

Comment: @hungerstar I'm now following the instructions on this page: https://octicons.github.com/usage/ word for word.

I replaced the <span class="col-md-5 w-icon"><img src="images/paint-format.svg"></span>

With:

<span class="octicon octicon-flame"></span>

And I still have no luck

Comment: You must have missed something with the _octicons_. With a modification of the `url()` in the `@font-face` declaration to use a cdn hosted copy of the icon font I was able to use them in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsuhgygn/). Icon fonts will look nice and crisp an various resolutions as they're a vector format like SVG.

Comment: @hungerstar what do you mean by "with a modifaction the url() in the '@font-face declaration to use a cdn hosted copy..."

I'm not proficient in html/css jargon

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR. Skipped to this:

> A) appear to be white when not hovered over and; B) transition
>   (smoothly) to orange when hovered over

I made these demo awhile ago, but I think you might find them helpful:

1. [Simple Demo](http://jsbin.com/hetaya/3/edit?html,js,output)
2. [Thorough Demo](http://jsbin.com/hetaya/5/edit?html,js,output)